# Golang Parametric polymorphism?

Tags: go

I wrote a function in order to get the standard deviation from a 
array of floats, but I'm have a problem, how can I use it 
if I have a array of ints?
I dont want to have a function for every data type...

```
func StdDev(a []float64) float64 {
    var Prom float64
    sum := 0.0
    Total := 0.0
    n := len(a)
    N := float64(n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        sum += a[i]
    }
    Prom = sum / N
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        Total += (a[i] - Prom) * (a[i] - Prom)
    }
    Total = Total / N
    Total = math.Sqrt(Total)
    return Total
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go has no generics, so you are not able to write a solution that covers `[]int` and `[]float64` at the same time. You have to copy the values from your `[]int` to a `[]float64` using a simple for-loop and a [type conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from `int` to `float`. Then you can use your function. Example ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/nvXwGh7-5T)):

```
a := []int{1,2,3,4}
b := make([]float64, len(a))

for i := range a {
    b[i] = float64(a[i])
}

StdDev(b)
```

What you can also do is to write a function based on reflection values and then use [`reflect.MakeFunc`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeFunc). This would be slower, harder to make and more code to write so the benefit is questionable.

#### Code style

Although this is off-topic I can't help but noticing that your code may look nicer if you would use [range clauses](http://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause) for your loops. Also, variables in a function body are written in lower caps. There are some other syntactic tricks such as [named return values](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types). Utilizing these features of Go, your code may look nicer:

```
func Avg(a []float64) (sum float64) {
    for i := range a {
        sum += a[i]
    }
    return sum / float64(len(a))
}

func StdDev(a []float64) (total float64) {
    prom := Avg(a)

    for i := range a {
        total += (a[i] - prom) * (a[i] - prom)
    }

    total = total / float64(len(a))

    return math.Sqrt(total)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices,I have a question,what about performance using range vs typical C-for-loop approach?

Comment: Using `range` can be [faster](http://zhen.org/blog/go-vs-java-decoding-billions-of-integers-per-second/) than using the C for-loop construct. So I would advise you to use `range`.

Comment: @nemo Why is that exactly? Surely its the same under the hood?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead My guess is that for-range blocks omit repeated boundary checks but I do not have time to check up on that. If you have the time, you could check `walkrange()` in `cmd/gc/range.c` for a start.

Comment: Had a quick look - from what I can gather it would appear to do more than that by incrementing the pointer, type checking (what its iterating over) and a bit of range checking. I'd say its potentially slower. In saying that - the difference is probably so minuscule that it makes no difference.. I just wondered thats all.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Except that [it is not slower](https://gist.github.com/zhenjl/7495442), it is faster. Just checked by running that benchmark. So a 'quick look' does not do justice here...

Comment: I didn't even think about benchmarking it - *facepalm*. Interesting! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Is this really the preferred solution in go? it seems crazy to have to convert an array of ints to floats to avoid the limitation of not having parametric polymorphism.

Comment: @SeanGeoffreyPietz Yes, also see the [Go FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq). No implicit conversions and generics for sake of language simplicity.

Comment: @nemo Would it not be recommended to just write a separate function for integers? I imagine it's pretty inefficient performance-wise to convert them all to floats if you're analyzing big data sets. I think this a good example of why go should add generics. I think adding generics would make the language simpler rather than more complex -- a lot of the workarounds/hacks I've seen people use to get around these problems are pretty damn complex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interfaces, just like the [sort package](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) does:

http://play.golang.org/p/4N_UpFScoU

```
package main

import "math"

type Adder interface {
    Add(a float64) float64
}

type floatAdder float64

func (f floatAdder) Add(a float64) float64 {
    return float64(f) + a
}

type intAdder int

func (i intAdder) Add(a float64) float64 {
    return float64(i) + a
}

func StdDev(a []Adder) float64 {
    var Prom float64
    sum := 0.0
    Total := 0.0
    n := len(a)
    N := float64(n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        sum = a[i].Add(sum)
    }
    Prom = sum / N
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        Total += a[i].Add(-Prom) * a[i].Add(-Prom)
    }
    Total = Total / N
    Total = math.Sqrt(Total)
    return Total
}

func main() {
    floats := []Adder{floatAdder(1.0), floatAdder(2.0), floatAdder(3.0)}
    println(StdDev(floats))

    ints := []Adder{intAdder(1), intAdder(2), intAdder(3)}
    println(StdDev(ints))
}
```

Comment: While this is certainly a possibility, I am not sure whether this is a good choice since it adds quite a few bits of complexity. Especially if the alternative is a simple type conversion.

Comment: How scale this with huge data arrays?

Comment: I'd say "process took too long" answers the scaling question.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

As of August 20, 2021, GoLang has a [Type Parameters Proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md) to add parametric polymorphism, or generics, to GoLang.

> We currently expect that this change will be available in the Go 1.18 release in early 2022

Under that proposal, the capabilities of interfaces will be expanded to include Type Sets, which can Union different types.

The proposal gives an example of doubling a list of numeric elements, which should help clarify how parametric polymorphism can solve problems like the `StdDev` one:

```golang
// Double returns a new slice that contains all the elements of s, doubled.
func Double[E constraints.Number](s []E) []E {
    r := make([]E, len(s))
    for i, v := range s {
        r[i] = v + v
    }
    return r
}
```

There is a discussion on the constraint package API [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45458), and the source can be viewed [here](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/349709/4/src/constraints/constraints.go).

There does not appear to be a `constraints.Number` or `constraints.Numeric`, so you would need to make one, but that is simple:

```golang
type RealNumber interface {
    Integer | Float
}
```

And then the syntax of your function should be straightforward:

```golang
func StdDev[E RealNumber](data []E) float64 {
    // determine the mean
    sum := 0.0
    for _, datum := range data {
        sum += datum
    }
    mean := sum / len(a)

    // calculate the variance
    sum = 0.0
    for _, datum := range data {
        deviation := datum - mean
        sum += deviation * deviation
    }
    variance := sum / len(a)

    return math.Sqrt(variation)
}
```